# Is it ok to create an endpoint to manually refresh a JWT?

Tags: api, security, jwt

In an app, we are keeping some trivial boolean values in the JWT payload.

On certain UI actions the boolean values change on the server and the app needs to get a fresh token to reflect this change.
To get a fresh token, the browser can hit an endpoint that will check and validate their current token, and then return a new access token. To be clear, a user must have a valid access token to be able to get a new access token from the endpoint.

Is this a security issue or is it ok to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application issued the token in the first place, it should be fine to have it renew the token also. I don't think there are specific security concerns around this scenario. If another authority issued the token, your application cannot renew it as it should not have access to the signing key for the digital signature.

Whether it's a good idea to keep UI related info in the security token is another thing. These values are probably better stored in session info or client side storage.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I should have been more specific. Basically, there are user flags like 'emailVerified'. So I don't consider it UI data, but it is changed based on UI actions like visiting the validation url with the right parameters. It is not UI state, it is application state. 

There are other similar flags but they are also just application state that I want refreshed on certain UI actions. Does this sound ok?

Comment: There are no rules as to what can and cannot go into a token. Typically you only want to store info that does not change often as tokens are digitally signed and if one of the claims changes, you need to reissue the token. Something like email_verified I would consider authentication related and okay to be in the token.

Answer (score 0):

**What I got** -

If it's okay to have an endpoint to refresh the token given an access token for the user?

**The answer to the above** -

Yes that's perfectly fine and as McdD explained, if the same application has generated the access token, then it's perfectly fine for the same application to refresh it.

In fact, the smaller the expiry time of the access token, the better it is (according to how JWT works, most of the application keeps it in minutes to hours), and refreshes the token after the access token expires (this is done to safeguard from misuse of the access token).